# Passing a variable into a ssh session

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm new to bash scripting so bear with me. I have a script that does some local stuff and then proceeds to ssh into a server to execute a script there. This is the main.sh:

```
read -p "Comment: " yn
Echo $yn
ssh user@whatever.com << EOF
  cd public_html/subdir/
  sh db/push.sh
EOF
```

And the file on the server (push.sh) does:

```
mysqldump -u user -ppassw dbname > db/db_sync.sql
git commit  -am "$yn"
git push
```

So basically I need the value $yn (which is user input) passed over the ssh and into push.sh. If I put the 'read' IN the ssh codeblock it just skips it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try the following?

Client side:

```
read -p "Comment: " yn
Echo $yn
ssh maikelva@maikelvanhees.com << EOF
  cd public_html/hackerfit/
  sh db/push.sh "$yn"
EOF
```

Server side:

```
mysqldump -u user -ppassw dbname > db/db_sync.sql
git commit  -am "$1"
git push
```

Comment: It works, having some github merge problems now, but that should be fixable :) Thanks a bunch! SPent 2 hours looking for that :)

Comment: Oddly enough had a co-worker do the same thing about a week ago

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
read -p "Comment: " yn
echo $yn
ssh user@whatever.com << EOF
  cd public_html/subdir/
  yn="$yn" sh db/push.sh
EOF
```

No need to change whatever.com side script.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree with Dave G.

Give it as a parameter as $yn is expanded by your local shell already